# How to create simple Android studio pop up window with EditText field for data insertion

Tags: android, android-edittext, popup, window, message

I've done a lot of search and there seems to be stuff only about error windows or strange menus/different activities.

What I want is just a simple pop up window with an `EditText` field and an OK button.

What should I use? How do I use it?

Oh and... Is it possible to do this only with Java? (without .xml files)

Comment: I figured out that there is no easy way. xml. file is required. But there is a very nice example even for those who doesn't know how to handle .xml My source : http://www.pcsalt.com/android/create-alertdialog-with-custom-layout-using-xml-layout/  
ofcourse I adapted everything to my program. 
I just wonder - is there a way to do UI in different java files? Because it only started to work after I put everything into MainActivity file

Answer (score 5):

**What should I use?**

You can use Alert dialog for simple pop-up.

**How do I use it?**

```
  AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

  final EditText et = new EditText(context);

  // set prompts.xml to alertdialog builder
  alertDialogBuilder.setView(et);

  // set dialog message
  alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        }
     });

  // create alert dialog
  AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
  // show it
  alertDialog.show();
```

Hope this helps

Comment: and if i want to put some another element such as textview... where should i add it into?

Comment: @gumuruh You can set any layout you wish to. Use the following code snippet.

final View customLayout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null);builder.setView(customLayout);

Answer (score 0):

you may use this.... but it requires xml.

```
public class confirmPop extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.pop);

        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
        int Width=dm.widthPixels;
        int height = dm.heightPixels;

        getWindow().setLayout((int)(Width*.8),(int)(height*.5));

    }

    public void onpopbtnclick(View v){
        Intent I = new Intent(this,Easy.class);
        startActivity(I);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that there is no easy way. xml. file is required. But there is a very nice example even for those who doesn't know how to handle .xml My source : http://www.pcsalt.com/android/create-alertdialog-with-custom-layout-using-xml-layout/
ofcourse I adapted everything to my program. 
I just wonder - is there a way to do UI in different java files? Because it only started to work after I put everything into MainActivity file.

Answer (score 0):

```
final AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ThisActivity.this);
View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.yourpopup, null);

final TextView text= view.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
Button button= view.findViewById(R.id.button1);

mBuilder.setView(view);
final AlertDialog dialog = mBuilder.create();

mChangPwBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //something
        }
    });

dialog.show();
```

Comment: An explanation, what a code does and how this addresses the problem in the question, rarely fails to improve an answer.